# Trying to understand why this execution overflows

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I would like to know/learn in more detail mechanism why [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/Ssyl07) throw a stack overflow error ? (.Net Fiddle link)

(Related to the fact that DisplayType is present in both the Interface and the abstract class, renaming the later make it work. I would like to understand what is the execution path that lead to this overflow).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("--------BEGIN--------");
    
        FIVan van = new FIVan();
        van.DisplayType();
    
        Console.WriteLine("---------END---------");
    }
}

public interface IVan
{
    public Type TheType {get;}
    public void DisplayType() => Console.WriteLine("Generic Type associated with this IVan<T> is : " + TheType.ToString());
}

public abstract class AVan<T> : IVan
    where T : class
{
    public Type TheType { get => typeof(T);}
    // NOTE : renaming DisplayType to something else (like Display()) doesn't Stack Overflow, it works.
    public void DisplayType() => ((IVan)this).DisplayType();
}

public class FIVan : AVan<FileInfo>
{
}
```

**EDIT :**
Actually I didn't fully realize how default interface implementation work. I add this edit to point you to [this](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/default-implementations-in-interfaces-in-c-sharp-8/) article I found interesting about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AVan<T>.DisplayType()` overrides the default interface implementation specified by `IVan.DisplayType()`.  So it just calls itself recursively indefinitely.

If `AVan<T>.DisplayType` is renamed, it calls into the default interface implementation instead, so does not cause a stack overflow.

Comment: Thank you, I had a misconception of what default interface implement are. I though as you have to explicitly implement them in derived class (the "=>" is a syntactic sugar to avoid this explicit implement, right ?) like `public abstract class AVan<T> : IVan   
{ void IVan.DisplayType() { Console.Writeline("blabla");}    
    public void DisplayType() => ((IVan)this).DisplayType(); }`
by casting `(IVan)this` we avoided override. 
Can't we use `new` keyword ?

Comment: If you never want any implementer of the interface to override this method, I would recommend an extension method on IVan instead - it will seem exactly the same but will not be able to be overridden.